# Procedure to implement ads into Android?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I've finished making a specialized calculator app, and it's growing quite well on Play, which gave me the idea to make ads on the app, but I have no idea how to do so. I've watched multiple youtube tutorials, read through the official documentation, but I alway get the same error. I've imported everything, added the necessary libraries into Eclipse, whatever. I've set up an admob account and I have the publisher ID all set up. The problem I get is when I'm implementing and putting the banner ad code into the XML code. The basic gist of what I get is that it doesn't recognize the com.google.adView object, in the same way it recognizes a Button or a View.

Since I'm pretty sure that this isn't my only mistake, could someone write a little list on what I need to do to implement ads?

Comment: You should post all your relevant code and the `LogCat` log if you're getting some exception, pointing out which is the line within your code that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the google-playservices project found in

```
[android sdk directory]\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
```

[Here is a link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/) that explain how to include admob, too many steps, but straightforward.

Comment: I tried to import the library project, but when I go into the "add library" part it shows an empty list so I can't choose the Google Play library. What should I do?

Comment: how did you import it?

Comment: Leave the project on its path (dont copy it manually), and make sure when you import it that "Copy projects into workset" is checked